# How to show some indicator if text width is larger than in TEdit's width

Tags: delphi, vcl

It is a common practice to show ellipsis (`...`) at the end of a text if it is too long to show in a text control.  For example:

```
This is a long text...
```

The `...` indicate there are more text.

For Delphi VCL TEdit control, is there a way to show ellipsis or other means to indicate if the text width is larger than TEdit's width?

Comment: Edit controls are for editing rather than displaying. How is the user going to edit the true value if you've replaced the data with an ellipsis. You are looking for a label. Or if you need an edit then make it larger or accept that the user will have to navigate.

Comment: @David: Edit controls are for displaying also. If some edit field contains long text, user will have to navigate to edit - it is ok. But he can't be sure that he sees full value, the only way is to check (start editing and try to scroll), and it is not ok. So i think question is useful (besides the fact that there is no good solution with standard controls).

Comment: @Andrei How can you see the whole content if it has been replaced by ellipsis? Primary use case is for editing. For a navigateable read only text display I suggest static text is better.

Comment: Actually, static text probably cannot be selected.

Comment: @David: Of course you can't see whole value, if it is too long to fit the control. But you can know the fact, that value is longer. For example you see "Hello kitty." and you happy, because it look like good header for email. But with hidden part it could be "Hello Kitty. Damn It.". If you see something like "Hello kitty...", then you know that there is something more, than just "Hello Kitty" and in some cases it can be useful.

Comment: Put something outside the edit then. A label perhaps: "this edit has more content than to fit in". Awesome!

Comment: In some GUIs, if the contents are longer than the edit box, you can see a red right arrow directly beside the text. I think you could place an image of a red arrow directly beside the textbox (or a label with red text and an arrow symbol) and only make it visible if the text doesn't fit.

Comment: I don't believe it is really a common practice.

Answer (score 4):

As simple workaround, you can use OnEnter/OnExit events. When focus leaves control, you can check, if value doesn't fit, then replace it with something shorter and marker ("..." for example). Store original value and restore it when user start editing again:

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    procedure Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
    StoredValue: string;
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edit1.Text := StoredValue;
end;

procedure TForm2.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
const
  Tail = '...';
var
  SrcTextSize,TailSize,ShortedTextSize: TSize;
  ShortedTextWidth: integer;
  DC: HDC;
  StoredObj: HGDIOBJ;
begin
  DC := GetDC(Edit1.Handle);
  try
    StoredObj := SelectObject(DC, edit1.Font.Handle);
    try
      StoredValue := edit1.Text;
      GetTextExtentPoint32(DC, PChar(StoredValue), Length(StoredValue), SrcTextSize);
      if SrcTextSize.cx>Edit1.ClientWidth then
      begin
        GetTextExtentPoint32(DC, PChar(Tail), Length(Tail), TailSize);
        GetTextExtentExPoint(DC, PChar(StoredValue), Length(StoredValue),
          Edit1.ClientWidth-TailSize.cx, @ShortedTextWidth, nil, ShortedTextSize);
        edit1.Text := Copy(StoredValue,1,ShortedTextWidth) + '...';
      end;
    finally
      SelectObject(DC, StoredObj);
    end;
  finally
    ReleaseDC(Edit1.Handle, DC);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: One might want to use EM_GETMARGINS/EM_GETRECT to be more accurate, but I think this is quite enough for demonstration purposes. :)